# Give developers access to table create scripts for an MS SQL Server (production server) with only read rights?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

We have a production MS SQL Server and development MS SQL Server. As a developer I only have read rights on the production server. However, often I would like to replicate the create script of the production environment. Right now I just found out that my development table doesn't have it's indecies, but production does. I just asked DB operations (who have admin rights to production) to give me the create script via e-mail. This seems cumbersome. There are no business reasons why developers shouldn't be able to have access to these scripts, so that's not the reason it is restricted. Just a technical limitation. How do we give developers access to the create scripts of the production environment? I have access to do selects from production, just not able to do right-click-"Script Table as"-"CREATE To" on a table.

Any suggestions how I can do this myself, or ask DB operations to do so that developers have access to production environment scripts?

Comment: You really need to change how you work with databases

Comment: The question is perhaps better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tobsey How should we be working with "databases"? Do you have some resources we can draw from?

Comment: @Dan Thank you. I'll be sure to ask there next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the VIEW DEFINITION permission on the database level, to be able to script objects in the database. Ask your DB administrators to grant you this permission, and you should be good to go.

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808(v=sql.105).aspx)